# Java Enum : Having Multiple Strings within one Enums

Tags: java, enums

I am new student java learning its basics

My objective is to create a Enum which contains various categories like Emails, Username, Passwords, MaterialType etc. 
Further I wanted that within one Category I can declare various strings and my sample code is as below:

```
public enum MyEnums {
    Usernames
    {
        public String toString()
        {
            return "This is a GmailUsername";
        }
        /*public String toString()
        {
            return "This is a GalleryComment";
        }*/
    },
    Password
    {
        public String toString()
        {
            return "This is a public password";
        }
    /*  public String GmailPassword()
        {
            return "This is a Gmail Password";
        } */

    },
    Emails
    {
        public String toString()
        {
            return "This is a public contact email address";
        }
        /* public String EmailAccount()
        {
            return "This is a public Email Account address";
        } */

    },
    PhoneNumbers
    {
        public String toString()
        {
        return "This is Phonenumber";
        }
        /*  public String Phone()
        {
            return "This is a phone number";
        }*/
        }
    }
```

and I call the code as

```
public static void main (String args[])
   {

       System.out.println(MyEnums.Emails);
       System.out.println(MyEnums.Usernames );
       System.out.println(MyEnums.PhoneNumbers);
       System.out.println(MyEnums.Password);

   }
```

**My question is why on using second string type function it is giving error, example In the password category for GmailPassword() why it is not working.**

**Is there is any other way to declare multiple strings in enum in category wise manner like**

```
public Enum myEnum{
Category1
{
"String 1","String2",......."String N"
}
.......
.......
.......
.......
CategoryN
{
"String 1","String2",......."String N"
}
```

Comment: I think you should create a common interface for the strings and implement that for each enum value.

Comment: You are creating private anonymous inner classes for each `enum` constant. Only methods declared in the base class `MyEnum` can be accessed from the outside.

Comment: @Holger Sir please validate                                                      public Enum MyEnum
{
public String Category1(String s)
{
switch(s)
case 'Delete' :
“This is a string 1”;
case 'Update':
“This is a update”
case “Error”:
“You have validation Error”
}
}
and can call by
String s='delete'
System.out.println(MyEnum.Category1(s));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this helps?

```
 public enum MyEnum {
    Emails("mail1", "mail2", "mail3"), 
    Usernames("username1", "username2"), 
    CategoryN("a", "b", "c");

    private String[] strings;

    private MyEnum(String... strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(strings);
    }

    public String getString(int index) {
        return strings[index];
    }

}
```

Main

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyEnum.Emails);  //[mail1, mail2, mail3]

        System.out.println(MyEnum.Emails.getString(1)); //mail2
    }
```

Comment: +1 good approach. But shouldn't the string property be public final, or provide an accessor ?

Comment: @Pierre Henry: no it's not required but might be helpful. But you still need to remember that one could modify content of `strings` array.

Comment: How to call it in the main function I am calling it by using System.out.println(MyEnum.Emails); 
 System.out.println(MyEnum.Usernames); but not getting the single string instead I am getting whole enum.

Comment: Sir it helps and returning the data the way I need but don't know how to call it in main method. Please give me hints it will be your greatness.

Comment: Thank you sir :) I got What I needed the most love you sir @Criban

Comment: @Ajan : sure I didn't mean it was required. And yes, the content arrays could be modified, so maybe use an immutable list instead of an array, and make it public final ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an enum with Objects instead of just Strings. That way you can access all the properties of those objects in a clean manner.

Comment: Sir I am new to coding so it will be your greatness if you will programmatic illustration thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that instead of an Enum with categories, you should have an interface that you make each category enum implement. That way you have N enums that each implement the category interface, and inside each of those you have the strings as the enum constants.

Comment: please please give me an coding illustration of your approach.